populate azure devops pipeline parameters with branch names from a remote repository in the same project
We use multi repo structure for our apps. e.g in the same azure devops project we have separate repos for services like internal or external portal etc.
I have created a multi stage pipeline that lives in a different repo called overlays separate from services like e.g internal or external portals but in the same project. It poses a challenge that when i run this pipeline it cant see branches that are present in other repos e.g. internal portal. work around is to move my pipeline in e.g. internal portal repo but this creates another challenge.
When we are deploying releases whether from main branch or testing them from feature branches then pipeline will error Could not get the latest source version for repository if the branch doesn't exist e.g in external portal but present in internal portal.
trigger: none

pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

parameters:
- name: external_portal
  type: boolean
  default: false
- name: internal_portal
  type: boolean
  default: false

resources:
  repositories:
    - repository: templates
      type: git
      name: aks-templates/common-templates
      ref: refs/heads/main
    - repository: overlays
      type: git
      name: aks-microservices/overlays-and-services
      ref: refs/heads/main
     - repository: external-portal
       type: git
       name: aks-microservices/ExternalPortal
       ref: ${{ variables['Build.SourceBranch'] }}
    - repository: internal-portal
      type: git
      name: aks-microservices/InternalPortal
      ref: ${{ variables['Build.SourceBranch'] }}

variables:
  - group: common

stages:
 - ${{ if eq(parameters.external_portal, true) }}:
     - template: pipelines/templates/validate.yml@templates
       parameters:
         aksServiceName: 'external-portal'

- ${{ if eq(parameters.internal_portal, true) }}:
    - template: pipelines/templates/validate.yml@templates
      parameters:
        aksServiceName: 'internal-portal'

My question is: is there any way to create a parameter and populate it with list of existing branches from a remote repo to let user chose which one they want to deploy?
I have tried parameter of type "step" or "stepList" but not much luck.

we already doing it but i wanted to use a consolidated pipeline (1 per scheme) as currently we have 7 projects and about 140 pipelines.

another option would be to manually enter branch_name and variabilize it but again it will not be practical specially for day to day feature branch testings.

I suppose these comments are related to my answer? Well, in that case, you need to consider the pros and cons of each approach: multiple vs consolidated pipelines. Having less pipelines doesn't exactly mean that things are easier to maintain, as you already noticed when posting this question on SO. The branching issue alone might not be easy to manage.

Could you share more about the projects/repositories? It's ok to have shared templates in an external repository, but it would make your life easier if you had the pipelines in the same repositories of the apps you're trying to deploy.

When you say we have 7 projects and about 140 pipelines do you mean 7 Azure DevOps projects or 7 repositories? How many apps do you have per repository?

7 devops projects with 140 repositories each for different apps

"7 devops projects with 140 repositories each for different apps" - Ouch. I was expecting each repository to contain more than one app, so I was going to suggest 1 pipeline per repository. Anyway, having many repository resources per pipeline (one for each app) doesn't look a good approach to me, specially considering that each team will have its own naming conventions. As long as you're able to use common templates to build/deploy the apps I still believe having 1 pipeline per repository or app is the best approach. A lot of pipelines yes, but easy to manage. Keep it simple.

other alternatives could be that we take manual input as parameter before running the pipeline and then variablize ref. Or if the teams create branch for all the repos. but both of these options dont seem practical and if we cant populate by running git query then i think better stick to our current way of 1 pipeline per repo. really dont know why we have step or steplist as parameters when we cant use their output.

"I think better stick to our current way of 1 pipeline per repo" - yes, that seems to be the best choice.

So if I understand correctly, my proposed solution is more or less what you are already doing?

thats correct, just wanted to reduce the number of pipelines somehow

We have to define repo resources at compile time before pipeline runtime. therefore you cannot use a command/script at runtime to list branches then go back to compile time to tell repo resources to ref the expected branches. It is simply impossible. This is also why we have to explicitly specify the ref property of repository resources.

If you would expect one single pipeline generated with the YAML definition in your overlay repo to use other repos as resources, you have to explicitly define the ref lists for each resource. Still, you don't need to use every branch of every repo resource, do you? You may dynamically define the expected branches based on your logic to pick up a ref with the ${{if}} and ${{else}} expressions. That will reduce your work right?

@AlvinZhao-MSFT if or if-else would still require me to know what could be the name of a branch and probably i can ask devs to use a naming convention when deploying pipelines during a release session but this would still not cover scenario when 10s of devs are creating feature branches and testing them individually. They may choose any name for their temp branches.

Is there anyway i can assign a default value say "main" if ref: ${{ variables['Build.SourceBranch'] }} doesnt find any branch for a certain repo? This way the pipeline will not straight away fail at initial checks and if someone re-deploys a pipeline then it will be deployed from "main" and azure kubernetes being idompotent will run pipeline and make no changes.

If you directly use ref: ${{ variables['Build.SourceBranch'] }} for the repo resource, the pipeline is not a valid one when there is no existing ref. Like I suggested, you could explicitly define the which ref to be checked out at compile time before runtime, by adding multiple ${{if}} ${{elseif}} ${{else}} expressions; and you have to make sure the branch names for each repo resource are correct. That is already stated in the document I shared with you. So, I am afraid this is by-design. BTW the repo resource doesn't support any expressions in ref property at the very beginning.

You may also consider raising a feature request regarding the current limitation, but it may not be released in a near future.

I'd suggest you to create a separate pipeline for the External and Internal portals (or other applications).
You're already using a template (pipelines/templates/validate.yml@templates) so the code duplication will be minimal (e.g. duplicating some of the repository resources). But, on the other hand, you'll be able to run each pipeline independently and using different branches.
Also, I'd suggest having the pipeline in the same repository as the correspondent application - this will give you more flexibility when choosing the branch, as opposed to add a repository resource to your pipeline:

Internal Portal pipeline
Suggested implementation for the Internal portal pipeline:
trigger: none

pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

resources:
  repositories:
    - repository: templates
      type: git
      name: aks-templates/common-templates
      ref: refs/heads/main
    - repository: overlays
      type: git
      name: aks-microservices/overlays-and-services
      ref: refs/heads/main
    
    # Required? 
    # Can be removed if this pipeline is located in the same repository 
    # - repository: internal-portal
    #   type: git
    #   name: aks-microservices/InternalPortal
    #   ref: ${{ variables['Build.SourceBranch'] }}

variables:
  - group: common

stages:
  - template: pipelines/templates/validate.yml@templates
    parameters:
      aksServiceName: 'internal-portal'

External Portal pipeline
Suggested implementation for the External Portal pipeline:
trigger: none

pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

resources:
  repositories:
    - repository: templates
      type: git
      name: aks-templates/common-templates
      ref: refs/heads/main
    - repository: overlays
      type: git
      name: aks-microservices/overlays-and-services
      ref: refs/heads/main

    # Required? 
    # Can be removed if this pipeline is located in the same repository 
    # - repository: external-portal
    #   type: git
    #   name: aks-microservices/ExternalPortal
    #   ref: ${{ variables['Build.SourceBranch'] }}

variables:
  - group: common

stages:
  - template: pipelines/templates/validate.yml@templates
    parameters:
      aksServiceName: 'external-portal'


You may try with the sample pipeline below, When the pipeline is run with the code from main branch of overlays repo, it sets ref: main for both ExternalPortal and InternalPortal repo resources;  when the pipeline runs with the code from any other branch (feature) of overlays repo, it sets ref properties for both ExternalPortal and InternalPortal repo resources as the value you manually select from the picklists of the parameters.
trigger: none

pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

parameters:
- name: branches_external_portal
  displayName: Select branch ref of ExternalPortal repo resource when not using code in main branch of overlays
  type: string
  default: main
  values:
  - main
  - externalbranch
- name: branches_internal_portal
  displayName: Select branch ref of InternalPortal repo resource when not using code in main branch of overlays
  type: string
  default: main
  values:
  - main
  - Internalbranch


variables:
- ${{ if eq(variables['Build.SourceBranchName'], 'main') }}:
  - name: refExternal
    value: main
  - name: refInternal
    value: main
- ${{ else }}:
  - name: refExternal
    value: ${{parameters.branches_external_portal}}
  - name: refInternal
    value: ${{parameters.branches_internal_portal}}

resources:
  repositories:
  - repository: external-portal
    type: git
    name: aks-microservices/ExternalPortal
    ref: $(refExternal)
  - repository: internal-portal
    type: git
    name: aks-microservices/InternalPortal
    ref: $(refInternal)

steps:
- checkout: self
- checkout: external-portal
- checkout: internal-portal




As of now, we have to explicitly specify the ref property of repository resources with template expressions like those conditional insertions (${{if}} and ${{else}}) under the variables node. See more details on Template Expressions in Repository Resource Definition.

different teams create different branches using their own naming conventions so we are looking for 10s of potential branch names

As I mentioned, we have to explicitly specify the ref property of repository resources with template expressions. If you may need to use every branch of so many repo resources, use a YAML definition in an overlay repo may not be the best practice. Consider RUI's suggestion.

@DevOps-AS if each team has its own naming conventions for branches then I'm afraid a dynamic solution won't help, as Alvin Zhao already mentioned.

@Alvin Zhao, could you elaborate on "use a YAML definition in an overlay repo"? also i thought step or steplist would allow us to run e.g. git command to populate with list of branches but it literally just echo the query as an option. no idea if this is what it does or im not doing it right. i was hoping a value not the query but again it doesnt look like it supports parameters with steplist to be shown as selectable option

We have to define repo resources at compile time before pipeline runtime. therefore you cannot use a command/script at runtime to list branches then go back to compile time to tell repo resources to ref the expected branches. It is simply impossible. This is also why we have to explicitly specify the ref property of repository resources.
